# Basic question about existene of subgroups of a particular order of an abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Assume that $|G|=p^km$  where $p$ is a prime and $p\nmid m$. We know from Sylow's theorem that $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^k$. But is it true that $G$ has a subgroup of order $p^j$ for all $1\leq j\leq k$ ?

Comment: Yes, this follows easily by induction on $j$.

Comment: Yes...in particular any finite $p$ group has this property. So just take subgroups of the $p$ subgroup you already found. By the way, $G$ need not be abelian.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1603023

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is true! Even for non-abelian group.

> **Proposition.** Let $G$ be a finite group and $p$ be a prime divisor of the order of $G$, then for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^j$ divides the order of $G$, there exists $H\leqslant G$ such that $|H|=p^j$.

The proof relies on the following lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $G$ be a finite group and $H\triangleleft G$. If $B$ is a subgroup of $G/H$, let $A:=p^{-1}(B)$, one has: $$[G:A]=[G/H:B].$$

**Proof.** Let $p:G\twoheadrightarrow G/H$ be the canonical surjection, $p_{\vert A}:A\twoheadrightarrow B$ is a surjective group homomorphism whose kernel is $A\cap H=H$. The result follows from first isomorphism theorem. $\Box$

Then the proof goes like this:

**Step 1.** If $G$ is abelian of order $p^m$, $G$ admits a subgroup of index $p$.

If $G$ is cyclic, this is trivial, otherwise proceed by induction on $m$.

**Step 2.** If $G$ is non-abelian of order $p^m$ with $m\geqslant 1$, then $G$ has a normal subgroup of index $p$.

Proceed by induction on $m$ and use the lemma with $H$ being the center of $G$.

**Step 3.** If $G$ has order $p^m$ with $m\geqslant 1$, then for all $j\in\{0,\cdots,m\}$, there exists $H\leqslant G$ such that $|H|=p^j$.

**Step 4.** Conclude.

Comment: For step 1, it is a lot easier to find a normal subgroup of order $p$ than one of index $p$.