# A $p$-group of order $p^n$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for each $0\le k \le n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have referred the question already asked , i understood almost all but this line below -

"I know it contains $N_{k}$ and some stuff not in $N_{k}$, so it has to have order at least $p^{k+1}$, but I do not know how to argue it must be equal, or indeed if it even is equal."

link - [A $p$-group of order $p^n$ has a normal subgroup of order $p^k$ for each $0\le k \le n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549635/a-p-group-of-order-pn-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-pk-for-each-0-le-k)

Please help  with the above theorem.

Comment: I understood that $\pi^{-1}(C(G/N_k))$ is normal in $G$ , but what happens after that ? , how do we reach to conclude that $G$ contains a subgroup of orders of the form $p^{k}, 0 \leq k \leq n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Size}[1]{\left\lvert #1 \right\rvert}$The point is, $C(G/N_{k})$ has order divisible by $p$, hence [it has a subgroup of order $p$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). (You may also use induction, if you wish.)

By the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)) this subgroup has the form $H/N_{k}$, for some subgroup $H$ containing $N_{k}$.

Then $H$ has order $p^{k+1}$, [as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_(group_theory))
$$
p = \Size{\frac{H}{N_{k}}} = \frac{\Size{H}}{\Size{N_{k}}}
=
\frac{\Size{H}}{p^{k}}.
$$

Finally, $H$ is normal in $G$ because, again by the [correspondence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)), $H/N_{k}$ is normal in $G/N_{k}$, as every subgroup of $C(G/N_{k})$ is normal in $G/N_{k}$.