# If $G$ is a $p$-group, show that there is an epimorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm trying show that if a group $G$ has order $p^n$ then there exists a surjective homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p$.  I know from Cauchy's Theorem there is a cyclic subgroup of order $p$ and that will be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}p$, but what to do about the rest of the group, in order to ensure my mapping is a surjection, I don't know.

Comment: There is a normal subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$ by Sylow

Comment: Use the fact that $G$ has nontrivial center and induct on $n$.

Comment: @Randall: I don't follow. The Sylow theorems only tell you that there is a subgroup of order $p^n$, which in this case is all of $G$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan  I can't recall the precise argument, but I'm sure this is an exercise in Hungerford.  I remember proving it as a graduate student.  Horrible evidence, I know.  If my memory fails and I am wrong, I will retract.

Comment: Ah, of course, the argument is posted at this very site:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549635/a-p-group-of-order-pn-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-pk-for-each-0-le-k

Comment: The statement is definitely true but I don't think the Sylow theorems are relevant.

Comment: It may be possible to prove it without ST, but it's a stretch to say they're not relevant:  it depends on the version of ST at your disposal.  The version of Sylow theory that I learned from Fraleigh (that $G$ contains subgroups of order $p^k$ for all such divisors, not just the maximal one) is definitely relevant.  This version proves the normality of any subgroup of order $p^k$ in a subgroup of order $p^{k+1}$.

Comment: Any group of order $p^n$ contains subgroups of order $p^j$ for all $0 \leq j \leq n$. This is a fairly easy induction argument which exploits the fact that the center is nontrivial. You don't really need the Sylow existence theorem (i.s. that there exists a subgroup of order $p^n$ when this is the largest power of $p$ dividing $|G|$) for this, but some authors do include the smaller powers of $p$ in their statement of that theorem.

Comment: I would always advocate for a simple induction over Sylow theorems, for sure.

Comment: P.S. The key result you use here is that there is a **normal** subgroup of each possible order (hence a homomorphism with that subgroup as a kernel). This is part of the induction argument as well, but I don't think it's usually included even in the more general statement of the Sylow existence theorem. (I could be wrong.)

Comment: @anomaly I've been staring at it for hours, maybe I'm just tired, but not seeing how to do the induction.  $G$ has a non-trivial center and its size is a $p$-power, but I don't see what to do with it.  The class equation?  Mod out by it?  Since I don't know how big the center is, I'm not guaranteed that the center is the kernel of the surjective homomorphism.

Comment: @Randall Since I don't think I have the theorem that a $p$-group has normal subgroups of every $p^k, k\leq n$ then proving it in order to solve the problem seems like it'd be too much.

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Some authors include the part about subgroups of all prime power orders as part of the Sylow theorems (I don't like this myself, as it is really a statement about subgroups of $p$-groups, while the Sylow theorems are specifically useful for non- $p$-groups).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume the result holds for all $p$-groups $G'$ with $|G'| < |G|$. The quotient $G/Z(G)$ then admits a surjection $G/Z(G) \to \mathbb{Z}_p$, and the composition $G \to G/Z(G) \to \mathbb{Z}_p$ is also surjective.