# Do Sylow's theorems tell us that there exists at least one subgroup of order $p^i , i=\{1,2, ...,n\}$ if $|G|=p^na$?

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Do Sylow's theorems tell us that there exists at least one group of order $p^i , i=\{1,2, ..., n\}$ if $|G|=p^na$ ?

---

The textbook that I have doesn't say anything about that, is this trivial am I missing something ?

For example let $|G|=5^9\cdot  3$ does that mean that $G$ has subgroups with order  $5,5^2,5^3,...,5^9$ ?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: There are multiple ways of stating Sylow's Theorems. Some of them include this as part of their statement. Other ways of stating it do not, and you must deduce it from other results, such as the existence of Sylow $p$-subgroups and the class formula. So you need to say exactly how the theorems are phrased, and what other results you may or may not know related to this.

Comment: @Shaun it's a Greek textbook, you probably don't know it.

Comment: In my experience, existence is pretty commonly included, but I suppose that need not be universally true.  (Would seem strange not to.)

Comment: @Randall ok, it's true then, I will try to prove it if so.

Comment: Still: it might be of use to *someone*. I didn't ask for my benefit. Please share the details.

Comment: You didn't ask, but to me the most readable treatment of all this is in Fraleigh's book.  I was confused about this for far too long before I encountered Fraleigh's treatment (which is not unique to Fraleigh).

Comment: @Shaun the book is called "an introduction to algebra" it's by the EKPA university, I don't think it's even translated in English.

Comment: Thank you. Some users here know Greek.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/549635/a-p-group-of-order-pn-has-a-normal-subgroup-of-order-pk-for-each-0-le-k